# Drupal add fieldset inside form and wrap all form elements under that fieldset

Tags: 7, forms

I want to add fieldset tag inside form tag. Also i want to wrap all the form element under this fieldset. I'm using the following function to change the form design and html.

MY CODE:

```
function change_password_form($form, &$form_state) {
  if (user_is_anonymous()) {
    return $form; // Or drupal_access_denied()?
  }
  $form['#account'] = $GLOBALS['user']; 
  $form['fieldset']['current_pass'] = array(
    '#type' => 'password',
    '#title' => t('Current password'),
    '#size' => 25,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  return $form;
}
```

CURRENT OUTPUT :

```
<form action="/projects/drupal/hpedu/change-password" method="post" id="change-password-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div>
<div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-current-pass">
  <label for="edit-current-pass">Current password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <input type="password" id="edit-current-pass" name="current_pass" size="25" maxlength="128" class="form-text required">
</div>
<div class="form-actions"><input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Submit" class="form-submit"></div><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-pGcx3HehTZlOkicX1gaBrr5eBjv8iT6iccQvCN8uXTU">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="1qygden7YqhLlXvjiC8-ypYDXhOKwW_brUB4BdXlKNU">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="change_password_form">
</div>
</form>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT :

```
<form action="/projects/drupal/hpedu/change-password" method="post" id="change-password-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<fieldset class="myclass"> <!-- This Fieldset , which i want to add --> 
<div>
<div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-current-pass">
  <label for="edit-current-pass">Current password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <input type="password" id="edit-current-pass" name="current_pass" size="25" maxlength="128" class="form-text required">
</div>
<div class="form-actions"><input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Submit" class="form-submit"></div><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-pGcx3HehTZlOkicX1gaBrr5eBjv8iT6iccQvCN8uXTU">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="1qygden7YqhLlXvjiC8-ypYDXhOKwW_brUB4BdXlKNU">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="change_password_form">
</div>
</fieldset>  <!-- This Fieldset , which i want to add --> 
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this.

```
function change_password_form($form, &$form_state) {
  if (user_is_anonymous()) {
    return $form; // Or drupal_access_denied()?
  }

  $form['#account'] = $GLOBALS['user']; 

  // To make the fieldset define #type as fieldset
  $form['fieldset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Password Info'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE, // Added
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,  // Added
  );

  $form['fieldset']['current_pass'] = array(
    '#type' => 'password',
    '#title' => t('Current password'),
    '#size' => 25,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  return $form;
}
```